# Wander around airport connecting flight Schiphol

Tags: transit, uk-citizens, connecting-flights, ams, russian-citizens

I am flying on a flight from London - Schiphol (AMS) soon and then outbound to Moscow.

My layover time is around 3 hours. In this time I would like to wander around the airport, look at the shops and hopefully have something to eat.

Last time though, when I flew the same route, I was stuck in the connecting flight lounge and couldn’t look around without re-entering the airport.

So my question is will I be put in the connecting flight lounge again or will I be able to wander around?

And if I am put in the connecting flight lounge is there any point for me to re-Enter the airport?

Comment: What do you mean by the "connecting flight lounge"?  What is your citizenship?

Comment: @Doc uk citizenship and ru citizenship

Comment: If you have a British passport you can certainly pass EU immigration if you wish. What do you mean by the "connecting flight lounge"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the "connecting flight lounge", however...

Your flight will be considered an "International to International" connection, as you are coming from and going to a country that is outside of the Schengen area that the Netherlands is located in.  This means you will be able to spend the time before your flights in the international departure area of the airport, which has all sorts of shops, including food shops.

As you have a UK passport, you will even be allowed passed through immigration and enter the country, at which point you will be able to access any of the shops that are landside, or even hop a train to downtown Amsterdam - although with only 3 hours between flights I wouldn't recommend doing that!

Comment: Just arrived and this was exactly the case

Answer (score -4):

I'm afraid this time will be similar. The UK, EU and Russia have different visa support in such occasions for passengers support Schiphol has the connecting lounge (you don't to pay or trouble about visa).

But if you want to visit things outside this area you have to leave it and it is mandatory to have a legal reason to enter EU (like visa or passport from a country who has visa-free status with EU).